# What is an alternative to breakfast cereal with a comparable cooking time and sugar content?

Tags: food, junkfood

Some children do not like the taste of breakfast cereal, even when it contains a lot of sugar and/or high-fructose corn syrup.

Can you provide the name of an alternative culinary dish which has comparable, or similar amounts, of carbohydrates, but a different flavor which may be more appealing to the child?

Comment: As a mom, I would be perfectly happy with kids declining the typical sugary breakfast cereal products, we spent a lot of effort to gently steer our kids away from them, particularly because of their sugar content. If you could include the underlying motivation of your question, your post may be better understood and consequently received by the community. Btw., what cooking time are you referring to?

Comment: Toast with cheese, avocado, or pb/banana.

Answer (score 2):

Breakfast cereals are not all that healthy, often contain a lot of sugar, and there's nothing special about the nutrients they provide. I also think the concept of a breakfast food is quite flexible with kids, so as long as they're getting carbohydrates, ideally with a little protein as well, that counts as breakfast.

Some quick morning options:

- Yogurt with fruit
- Bagel with cream cheese
- Cheese and crackers
- peanut butter sandwich or cheese sandwich/toast

Or make ahead and reheat as needed:

- porridge
- boiled eggs
- pancakes
- rice
- muffins or scones
- Any leftover foods the child prefer that supply the desire
  nutritional profile

Comment: I think your second and fouth bullet point are both subsets of the common breakfast of any kind of bread combined with butter, jams, honey, spreads or cheese and cold cuts.

Answer (score 0):

Chocolate chip cookies and milk contain an amount of sugar which is similar to that some some breakfast cereals and may or may not provide a flavor profile which the child prefers over breakfast cereal.

Instead of chocolate chip cookies, it may be possible to cook South American gorditas, or "Naan" flat bread from India, with fresh strawberries or apple juice concentrate mixed into the bread dough substituted for typical sweeteners. In this context typical sweeteners are defined to be refined white-colored sugar, corn syrup and/or honey.